# Porting SyncToy 2.0 Folder Pairs to New Profile

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles, synctoy

I recently had to reload my profile on Windows XP Professional.  Basically, my profile folder was renamed to name_old, and my profile was reloaded to the same location at C:\Documents and Settings\name.  Now, all my SyncToy folder pairs are gone!  Does anyone know how to port over the old folder pairs?  Would this information be buried in the application data folder somewhere, or perhaps in the registry?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folder pairs are located in "C:\Documents and Settings\name_old\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\SyncToy\2.0" You will need to copy over both the SyncToyDirPairs.bin and the .dat files to your new profile.

Answer (score 2):

From:

`C:\Documents and Settings\name_old\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\SyncToy\2.0`

You will need to copy over both the `SyncToyDirPairs.bin` and the `*.dat` files to your new profile. Is OK from Windows XP to Windows XP, but not from Windows XP to Windows 7.

Windows 7 user path is under `C:\users\%username%\` so you will need to re setup your pairs if moving to windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a change in the setup I recommend recreating the folder pairs manually as synctoy keeps unique id's for the synced files which may be derived from the environment.

To see what had been setup previously you can check the synctoy log at

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Synctoy\2.0\SyncToyLog.log